# Serialization not working in my JFrames

Tags: java, user-interface, serialization

I'm not sure why the albums aren't being serialized when the users are.
In the admin class, when I login, the `userlist` is populated in the `JCombobox<String> userlist` everytime I restart the program.
But the `JComboBox<Album> comboBoxAlbumSelect` isn't populated every time I restart the program.
Not sure why. Thanks.

Relevant code:

```
public class Admin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
Backend backend = new Backend();
GuiCtrl ctrl = new GuiCtrl(backend);
private JComboBox<String> userlist = new JComboBox<String>();

    public Admin() {
    //same as login
    userlist = new JComboBox<String>(getUserList());
}

public String[] getUserList() {
    String[] ret = new String[backend.getUserList().size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String s : backend.getUserList()) {
        System.out.println(s);
        ret[i++] = s;
    }
    return ret;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == logout) {
        this.dispose();
        new Login();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == add) {
        try {
        if (ctrl.adduser(idNumberTF.getText(), fullNameTF.getText())) {
            userlist.addItem(idNumberTF.getText());
            backend.storeData();
        } catch (IOException|ClassNotFoundException i) {}
    }
}
}
```

- ```
  public class MainAlbumPanelv2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JButton btnCreateAlbum = new JButton("Create");
  JComboBox<Album> comboBoxAlbumSelect = new JComboBox<Album>();
  Backend backend = new Backend();
  GuiCtrl ctrl = new GuiCtrl(backend);
  User loggedInUser;

  public MainAlbumPanelv2(User id) {
      loggedInUser = id;
      comboBoxAlbumSelect = new JComboBox<Album>(getAlbumList());
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == btnCreateAlbum) {
          if (ctrl.createAlbum(loggedInUser, textFieldCreateAlbum.getText())) {
          Album newAlbum = new Album(textFieldCreateAlbum.getText());
          comboBoxAlbumSelect.addItem(newAlbum);
          }
          try {
          backend.storeData();
          } catch (IOException i) {}
      }
  }

  public Album[] getAlbumList() {
      Album[] ret = new Album[loggedInUser.getAlbums().size()];
      int i = 0;
      for (Album a : loggedInUser.getAlbums()) {
          System.out.println(a);
          ret[i++] = a;
      }
      return ret;
  }
  }
  ```

-

```
public class GuiCtrl {
User loggedInUser;
Backend backend;

    public GuiCtrl(Backend backend) {
        this.backend = backend;
    }

    public boolean adduser(String user_id, String user_name) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (backend.addUser(new User(user_id, user_name))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean createAlbum(User user_id, String name) {
        if (user_id.getAlbum(name) != null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            user_id.addAlbum(name);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
public class Backend {
    private HashMap<String, User> userList = new HashMap<>();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public Backend() {
        try {
            populateList();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read file");
        }
    }

    public boolean addUser(User newUser)
    {
        String userId = newUser.getID();
        if (userList.containsKey(userId)) {
            return false;
        }
        userList.put(userId, newUser);
        return true;
    }

    public void storeData() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("users.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            out.writeObject(userList);
            out.close();
            file.close();
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void populateList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream ("users.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            userList = (HashMap<String, User>) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            file.close();
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
            userList = new HashMap();
        }
    }
}
```

- ```
  public class Album implements Serializable{
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Photo> photoList;


  public Album(String name)
  {
      this.name = name;
      photoList = new ArrayList<Photo>();
  }
  }

  public class User implements Serializable{
  private String id;
  private String fullName;
  private ArrayList<Album> albumList;
  public User(String id, String fullName)
  {
      this.id = id;
      this.fullName = fullName;
      albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
  }
  public int addAlbum(Album newAlbum)
  {
      Album currAlbum;
      if (newAlbum == null)
      {
          return 0;
      }
      for (int x = 0; x < albumList.size(); x++)
      {
          currAlbum = albumList.get(x);
          if (currAlbum.getName().equals(newAlbum.getName()))
          {
              return 0;
          }
      }
      albumList.add(newAlbum);
      return 1;
  }
  public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums()
  {
      return albumList;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: not sure what need to be removed, unless u want me to remove the admin related stuff since that works?

Comment: Ideally, everything; "perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." Really, though, just try to cut it down from however many hundreds of lines you have to something under a hundred, otherwise it's just really hard to even consider it.

Comment: well i updated it, dunno what else can be removed

Comment: Your JFrames and JComboboxes don't have anything to do with this. Get rid of all the Swing code and reduce the problem to its essentials.

Comment: serialization was working before the transfer to gui though when it was just  console parsing

Comment: So you broke it. Compare the relevant code.